# TabBar select item change background color

Tags: ios, swift, tabbar

I try change background color, when user tap on tab bar item. My code:

```
//MARK: func
func settingTabBar(){
    //настроили бэкгроунд активного таб бара на зеленный цвет
    let numberOfItems = CGFloat((tabBarController?.tabBar.items!.count)!)
    let tabBarItemSize = CGSize(width: (tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.width)! / numberOfItems, height: (tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.height)!)
    tabBarController?.tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = UIImage.imageWithColor(color: Helpers.followGreenColor, size: tabBarItemSize).resizableImage(withCapInsets: .zero)

    // remove default border
    tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.size.width = self.view.frame.width + 4
    tabBarController?.tabBar.frame.origin.x = -2
}
```

Select item color changes but not completely. Look screen below. THX.

[image: my screen]

[image: my problem]

upd:

[image: screen view hierarchy]

Comment: Run your project and click on `debug view hierarchy` to see what's that white rectangle

Comment: @GustavoConde I update question

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with the following code

```
class ChildTabBarController: UITabBarController {

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            changeBckgColorSelection()
        }

        fileprivate func changeBckgColorSelection() {
                let imgSize = CGSize(width: tabBar.frame.size.width / CGFloat(tabBar.items!.count),
                                     height: tabBar.frame.size.height)
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(imgSize, false, 0)
                let p = UIBezierPath(rect: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: imgSize.width,
                                                  height: imgSize.height))
                Helpers.followGreenColor.setFill()
                p.fill()
                let finalImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
                self.tabBar.selectionIndicatorImage = finalImg
            }
    }
```